# java.io.NotSerializableException, even though I implemented the Serializable interface everywhere

Tags: java, android, interface, serializable

I have been struggling with this issue since yesterday evening and have not been able to find any solution to it over the web. I am developing an app using Android Studio and I want to save some instances to a local file (instances of the class `Table`). I have made sure that `Table` implements `java.io.Serializable`, along with all its components, but I somehow get the following error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; 
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.pewletthackard.waiterfocusapp.struct.Table
```

Even after declaring most of my fields as `transient`, with only 2 `Integer` fields left un-`transient`, I still manage to get this error message. This is some of my class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Table implements Serializable,Comparable<Table> {

private final Integer number;

private Integer peopleCovered;
private transient final AbstractShape shape;
private transient Status status = DefaultStatus.WELCOMED;
private transient Timer timer = new Timer(status);
private transient StatusFlow statusFlow;
...
```

The rest of the class is just made of constructors and getters/setters. Also, this is not an inner class. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are these classes "Status","Timer" and others are serializable as well? Because they also should be serializable.

Comment: As Shivam told you are making use of non serializable objects as attributes of the object you are trying to serialize. Take a look of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922897/serializable-and-transient . Transient / volatille are considered in compile time, not in runtime time were the exception occurs.

Comment: They are. Status is an interface though, but DefaultStatus is Serializable. But I have marked all those fields as transient in order to debug and, as I said, it is still giving me the same error message.

Comment: `public abstract class AbstractShape implements Serializable {`, `public enum DefaultStatus implements Status, Serializable {`, `public class Timer implements Serializable {`, `public class StatusFlow implements Serializable{` ; copied and pasted from my code

Comment: @Andrew is `Timer` a custom class or `java.util.Timer`?

Comment: @EduardoHerzer it's a custom class

Comment: All classes have serializable objects?

Comment: I would do the following: Comment all attributes from `Table` except `Integer peopleCovered` and verify it is working. Then uncomment the next attribute and verify if it is still working. And so on, until you get the error. This way you will know exactly which class has the problem and it might be easier to find a solution

Comment: @EduardoHerzer just rechecked. yes, they all have. and all the objects inside them as well and so on.