# How can I convert an object to a String in JavaScript, specifically the `document` object from a browser?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I can't use `JSON.Stringify` because the `document` object goes many many levels deep. I tried the function over at: http://www.davidpirek.com/blog/object-to-string-how-to-deserialize-json but I get an error `_o.hasOwnProperty is not a function`. Anyone have any advice or tips?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to serialize the document object?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Scraping the HTML (and all associated document information)

Comment: If you really want to pull down an entire page, with all scripts, stylesheets, images etc. you likely do not want to do it with JavaScript but instead using PHP/JSP/ASP... or good ole fashion wGet.

Comment: Except I want to do it while the user is on a page..

Comment: Please take a moment to explain your "end goal" there is very likely a much better way to accomplish whatever it is that you are *really* after.

Comment: What I want is for a user on page to send me back the full HTML of the page that they are on

Comment: This doesn't seem to make much sense... if you have the source of the page there's no point in them sending it to you... it will be huge, and you'll still have to parse it.  Any data you care about should be in the form... and if you want additional info, use JavaScript to put that info into a hidden form element (e.g. the mouse position, screen size, time on page, or whatever else you want).

Comment: why don't u use document.body.innerHTML ?

Comment: document.body doesn't seem to exist when I try to call it

Comment: I meant document.body.innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not serialize 'document' to JSON string using JSON.stringify, since it contains circular references. One way to deal with circular references is to implement your own stringify method, which keeps tracks of the circular references and excludes those. (see this answer: [How to solve circular reference in json serializer caused by hibernate bidirectional mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340485/how-to-solve-circular-reference-in-json-serializer-caused-by-hibernate-bidirecti))

As already said in the comments, do you really need to serialize the document object?

I've been working with a similar kind of project (time to advertise: http://hannotaatio.futurice.com) and we do not serialize document object. Instead, relevant information from document object is stored using JavaScript. The code is on Github so feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently one way to go is simply to use jQuery. I don't love it, but it'll do for now.