# Is there any json library for android which can manage circular reference?

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any json library for android which can manage circular reference ? I need to serialize one object which contains list of objects, where every object from list can contains list of objects of self type.

for example

```
class item{
LinkedList<item> list
}

class container{
LinkedList<item> list;
}
```

I have tried with Gson ( and Xtreme to xml ) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android will run whatever Java library you choose.

AFAIK, Gson doesn't handle circular references, but Jackson and XStream do.

Check out these threads for further info:

[How to solve circular reference in json serializer caused by hibernate bidirectional mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340485/how-to-solve-circular-reference-in-json-serializer-caused-by-hibernate-bidirecti)

[Jackson Vs. Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson)

**UPD** But you're probably better off adding ignore annotations to those back references.