# Exclude properties from serialization with GSON

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I am using gson to serialize my classes. I have some properties that implements an exclusion strategy to avoid circular references. Here is a simple example:

```
class A{
 B b;
}

class B implements ExclusionStrategy{
 A a
 String str;

 ... implements exclusion strat for class A

}
```

However, the exclusion strat on A is not called. It still tries to serialize property A in class B. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? If I just try to serialize class B, it works, so I know the exclusion strat works.

It just doesnt seem to be applied to properties of the containing class. Perhaps there is something I need to add to class A so it knows some of its properties do contain exclusion strategies?

EDIT:

The resulting JSON should look something like:

```
{
    B
    {
        'str':'some str'
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you implemented the exclusion? And how have you registered it? What do you want your resulting JSON to look like? Are you currently getting a stack overflow from the circular reference?

Comment: Yes, I am getting a stack overflow. I have implemented the exlcusion strategy in class B to avoid serializing class A. I am sure thats where the stackoverflow is coming from. Howver, I only ever serialize class A. Is there a way to register the exclusion classes if the are contained in class B even though I am serializing class A?

Comment: Are you using `GsonBuilder#setExclusionStrategies`?

Comment: Oh, do you want to skip `B.a` **only** if you're already serializing `A`? And vice versa? In other words, if you only serialize a `B`, you want the `A.b` to be skipped, and if you serialize an `A`, you want `B.a` to be skipped?

Comment: Yes, something along those lines. It just needs to be serialized once to avoid circular references

Comment: I don't think Gson is well suited for this. [Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3359884/438154) seems to have a better solution.