# Prevent certain fields from being serialized

Tags: json, serialization, playframework

In the Play framework i have a few models that have fields which are object references to other models. When i use renderJSON, i don't want those object references to be included. Currently for my needs i create a separate view model class which contains the fields i want, and in the controller i create instances of this view class as needed. Ideally i would like to be able to use the model class itself without having to write the view class.

Is there a way to annotate a field so that it will not be serialized when using renderJSON?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

because play uses Gson for its Json serialization you can try the following:

```
public static void test()  
{  
    Object foo = new SomeObject("testData");  
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT)  
        .create();
    renderJSON(gson.toJson(foo));  
}
```

now each field marked as transient will not be serialized. There is also another (better) way. You can use the `com.google.gson.annotations.Expose` annotation to mark each field you want to serialize.

```
public static void test()  
{  
    Object foo = new SomeObject("testData");  
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()  
        .create();
    renderJSON(gson.toJson(foo));  
}
```

Comment: thanks! a quick question, why do you say that using @Expose is better?

Comment: @Matias Elorriaga I personally like the explicit approach better :) It happens often to me, that i expose fields accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

Using [FlexJSON](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) with play is another option, explained in this article: http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2011/04/20/play-framework-better-json-serialization-flexjson

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why no one has written the most direct solution to this answer so I will do it here:

Simply mark the fields you do not want serialized via Gson as `transient`.

Here's an example:

```
public class Animal
{
        private String name = "dog";
        transient private int port = 80;
        private String species = "canine";
        transient private String password = "NoOneShouldSeeThis";
}
```

None of the items which are marked transient will be serialized.
When deserialized they will be set to their default (class default) values.

Resulting JSON will look like the following:

```
{"name":"dog","species":"canine"}
```

For more information on transient you can see the SO
[Why does Java have transient fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

I would override renderJSON to check a the field name against a member array of serialization exclusions.