# Which classes in a JSF web application need to be Serializable?

Tags: jsf, serialization

Does the `User` class from the question [JSF Controller, Service and DAO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao) need to be serializable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the server throws `java.io.NotSerializableException`, then the class name will just appear in the exception message. It's sufficient hint that the server expects the class to be `Serializable`.

Usually, it are those classes which (in)directly end up in the [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html), because the server may need to convert (serialize) all `HttpSession` instances to `InputStream`/`byte[]`, so they can be saved to local disk file system to remember open sessions during a restart, or transferred over network when being placed in a cluster.

In a JSF (+CDI) web application, all `@ViewScoped`, `@FlowScoped`, `@ConversationScoped` and `@SessionScoped` beans will (in)directly be saved in the `HttpSession`. So, it's obvious that at least those beans and all their properties need to be `Serializable`.

As to general design practice, anything which is classified as "Java Bean" throughout the codebase needs to implement `Serializable`. This is even mentioned in [JavaBeans Specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html). This only won't be actively used when it concerns e.g. a `@RequestScoped` or `@ApplicationScoped` bean, so that's why most developers just omit them from those beans. From the other side on, a `java.io.NotSerializableException` could be a good hint prevent the developers/maintainers from (re)using backing beans in the "wrong" scope than where the backing bean is originally designed for.

#### See also:

- [java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294551/java-io-writeabortedexception-writing-aborted-java-io-notserializableexception/)
- [What is a JavaBean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly)

Answer (score 1):

Every Class in your JSF application has to implement the `serializable` interface.

If you want to override this, use the `transient` keyword to skip serialization of unserializable classes.

***Additional info :***

- **Serialization of Objects explained:**

> It lets you take an object or group of objects, put them on a disk or send them through a wire or wireless transport mechanism, then
> later, perhaps on another computer, reverse the process: resurrect the
> original object(s). The basic mechanisms are to flatten object(s) into
> a one-dimensional stream of bits, and to turn that stream of bits back
> into the original object(s).
>
> Like the Transporter on Star Trek, it's all about taking something complicated and turning it into a flat sequence of 1s and 0s, then
> taking that sequence of 1s and 0s (possibly at another place, possibly
> at another time) and reconstructing the original complicated
> "something."
>
> *isocpp.org(Serialization and Unserialization)*

- [***What is the use of transient variables?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960280/what-is-the-use-of-transient-variables)