# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

Although this question asked many times and I have already used all the suggestion but still I am getting this error.

The User.java is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "LOCKED")
    private boolean locked;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Role.class)
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Override
    public GrantedAuthority[] getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthorityImpl> list = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthorityImpl>(0);
        for (Role role : roles) {
            list.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getRole()));
        }
        return (GrantedAuthority[]) list.toArray(new GrantedAuthority[list.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !isLocked();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return locked;
    }

    public void setLocked(boolean locked) {
        this.locked = locked;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
}
```

And the Role.java is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ROLE")
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ROLE_ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    private String username;
    @Column(name="ROLE")
    private String role;


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

This is my first attempt in hibernate annotation with JPA. So any suggestions will be very helpful.

For hibernate the pom.xml's dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have no clue about the fault.

Thanks.

Comment: You must use only @ManyToOne with @JoinColumn in this case since Role is an entity. You use @ElementCollection and @Column only when the collection contains basic types (Integer, String, Date, ect) or embeddable types. See examples in JPA 2.0 Specification if you want. You are combining annotations that are never used together and this could be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", updatable=false, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "LOCKED")
    private boolean locked;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Role.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Override
    public GrantedAuthority[] getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthorityImpl> list = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthorityImpl>(0);
        for (Role role : roles) {
            list.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getRole()));
        }
        return (GrantedAuthority[]) list.toArray(new GrantedAuthority[list.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !isLocked();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return locked;
    }

    public void setLocked(boolean locked) {
        this.locked = locked;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Role.java same as above.

Comment: It would be much better if you told what needs to be changed (and explain why) rather than posting the full code. One has to compare two files line-by-line to find the difference.

Comment: Comparing the files, I've found the following differences:
1. He's added @Access(AccessType.FIELD) to the class
2. @ElementColection on Set<Role> roles has been replaced with @JoinTable(...)

Answer (score 90):

I got the same problem with `@ManyToOne` column. It was solved... in stupid way. I had all other annotations for public getter methods, because they were overridden from parent class. But last field was annotated for private variable like in all other classes in my project. So I got the same `MappingException` without the reason.

Solution: I placed all annotations at public getter methods. I suppose, Hibernate can't handle cases, when annotations for private fields and public getters are mixed in one class.

Comment: Also avoid `lombok` for these classes because it changes where the annotations need to go.

Answer (score 60):

Adding the `@ElementCollection` to the List field solved this issue:

```
@Column
@ElementCollection(targetClass=Integer.class)
private List<Integer> countries;
```

Comment: What? This doesn't relate to the question.

Comment: Solved it for me without even specifying targetClass :)

Comment: `(targetClass=Integer.class)` is not needed in this case. That is only needed when your list is of a generic type

Comment: You don't need to specify `@Column` by default its `@Column` on every data member

Answer (score 18):

My guess is you are using a `Set<Role>` in the `User` class annotated with `@OneToMany`. Which means one `User` has many `Role`s. But on the same field you use the `@Column` annotation which makes no sense. One-to-many relationships are managed using a separate join table or a join column on the many side, which in this case would be the Role class. Using `@JoinColumn` instead of `@Column` would probably fix the issue, but it seems semantically wrong. I guess the relationship between role and user should be many-to-many.

Comment: @ElementCollection is also looking strange there. What's the purpose?

Comment: changing to @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Role.class, mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
 private Set<Role> roles; didn't solve the problem. I saw  some other thread that it is recommended to use  @ElementCollection that is why I use it.

Comment: The elementCollection isn't that used for components? Objects whose lifecycle follows the owning entity?

Answer (score 9):

Had this issue just today and discovered that I inadvertently left off the @ManyToMany annotation above the @JoinTable annotation.

Answer (score 5):

Not saying your mapping is correct or wrong but I think hibernate wants a instance of the set where you declare the field.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
//@ElementCollection(targetClass=Role.class)
@Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
```

Comment: I did it after you instruction. But didn't solve. If you want I can post complete stacktrace.

Comment: There is no need to use @ElementCollection in Role set because role is an entity. You must only use @ManyToOne in this case. The JPA 2.0 specification clearly states that @EllementCollection is for basic types and embeddables. Also, you must specify the column information using @JoinColumn, not @Column. This latter would be used with @ElementCollection, but not with @ManyToOne.

Comment: Sure post the stacktrace and edalorzo I know you are correct

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem I found the issue I was mixing the annotations some of them above the attributes and some of them above public methods. I just put all of them above attributes and it works.

Comment: Same here. You saved me from hours of debugging. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may just need to add `@Transient` annotations on roles to not serialize the set.

[Why does Java have transient fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I was getting an error for a member in the class that wasn't mapped to the db column, it was just a holder for a List of another entity. I changed List to ArrayList and the error went away. I know, I really shouldn't do that in a mapped entity, and that's what DTO's are for. Just wanted to share in case someone finds this thread and the answers above don't apply or help.