# @ElementCollection: Error Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, for columns

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

Here is my Entity class

```
    @Entity // Model Class as a DB entity
    public class UserDetails 
    {
        @Id 
        private int userId;
        private String name;

        @ElementCollection
        private Set<Address> listOfAddresses = new HashSet();

           // Setters and Getters Below

    }
```

Here is my Address Class

```
    @Embeddable
    public class Address 
    {
   private String Street;
   private String City;
   private String State;
   private String PinCode;

       // Setters and Getters Below
     }
```

Am using a standalone Java Class to try and insert into my **MySQL** database. Since, am new to Hibernate I just want to use this annotation and not the relations for now.

My standalone Java class named HibernateTest.java

```
       public class HibernateTest 
       {


      public static void main(String[] args) 
          {
    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    Address addr = new Address();
    user.setUserId(1);
    user.setName("Swateek");

    addr.setCity("Berhampur");
    addr.setPinCode("760001");
    addr.setState("Odisha");
    addr.setStreet("RKN");

    user.getListOfAddresses().add(addr);

    Address addrOff = new Address();

    addrOff.setCity("Bangalore");
    addrOff.setPinCode("560037");
    addrOff.setState("MTH");
    addrOff.setStreet("YH");

    user.getListOfAddresses().add(addrOff);

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();


    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction(); 
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit(); 
       }

   }
```

Now when I run the class HibernateTest I find this exception coming up. I have no clue why.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, for columns:
```

Comment: Duplicated question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164123/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-set Fixed it by using `java.util.List`

Comment: Not a duplicate. I wanted to use Sets. Is that collection choice a problem?

Comment: Even when I changed it. Am getting the same error. Any other suggestion pleasE?

Comment: What version of Hibernate do you use?

Comment: Hibernate 3. Should I use an upgraded version? Its just for practice though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@ElementCollection` is a part of JPA 2.0, which is supported by Hibernate since version 3.5.

If you version of Hibernate is older, you either need to upgrade it, or use similar Hibernate-specific annotation (`@CollectionOfElements`) instead.

Comment: I have tried with @CollectionOfElements too. But the same problem. I got no clue why since am new here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having @javax.persistence.ElementCollection annotation try using @org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements.