# Could not determine type for: java.util.Set

Tags: hibernate

this is my the classes user and catalog... one user have many catalog.

```
package com.egs.account.model;


import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String passwordConfirm;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dateRegistered;
    private Long skypeID;
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Catalog> catalogs;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() { return username; }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }

    public Date getDateRegistered() { return dateRegistered; }

    public void setDateRegistered(Date dateRegistered) { this.dateRegistered = dateRegistered; }

    public Long getSkypeID() { return skypeID; }

    public void setSkypeID(Long skypeID) { this.skypeID = skypeID; }

    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Set<Catalog> getCatalogs() { return catalogs; }

    public void setCatalogs(Set<Catalog> catalogs) { this.catalogs = catalogs; }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        final User other = (User) obj;
        final EqualsBuilder builder = new EqualsBuilder();
        builder.append(this.firstName, other.firstName);
        builder.append(this.lastName, other.lastName);
        builder.append(this.username, other.username);
        builder.append(this.skypeID, other.skypeID);
        return builder.isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserDocument [id=" + id + ", name=" + firstName + ", lastName="
                + lastName + ", username=" + username + "]";
    }
}
```

and this one is catalog class.

```
 package com.egs.account.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Catalog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String link;
    private String comment;
    private Date insertDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;

    @Lob @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name="content", nullable=false)
    private byte[] content;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLink() { return link; }

    public void setLink(String link) { this.link = link; }

    public String getComment() { return comment; }

    public void setComment(String comment) { this.comment = comment; }

    public Date getInsertDate() { return insertDate; }

    public void setInsertDate(Date insertDate) { this.insertDate = insertDate; }

    public User getUser() { return user;}

    public void setUser(User user) { this.user = user; }

    public byte[] getContent() { return content; }

    public void setContent(byte[] content) { this.content = content; }
}
```

And when running my application, I get this kind of exception.

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(catalogs)]

Anybody please tell me what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164123/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-set)