# JPA and Hibernate: ERROR 10844 could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: book, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(publishers)]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

It was working fine until i added the Publisher, with has the anotation @manytoone.

Code from Book.java

```
package com.example.TDSSpringTest.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity

public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private  String isbn;

    @ManyToOne
    private Publisher publisher;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "author_book", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
         inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))

    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Publisher> publishers = new HashSet<>();


    public Book (){

    }

    public Set<Publisher> getPublishers() {
        return publishers;
    }

    public void setPublishers(Set<Publisher> publishers) {
        this.publishers = publishers;
    }

    public Book(String title, String isbn) {
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }


    public Publisher getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(Publisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public Set<Author> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }

    public void setAuthors(Set<Author> authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", isbn='" + isbn + '\'' +
                ", authors=" + authors +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Book book = (Book) o;

        return id != null ? id.equals(book.id) : book.id == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

Code from Publisher.java

```
package com.example.TDSSpringTest.domain;


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Publisher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String adressLine1;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    public Publisher(){
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Publisher{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", adressLine1='" + adressLine1 + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", state='" + state + '\'' +
                ", zip='" + zip + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public Set<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Publisher publisher = (Publisher) o;

        return id != null ? id.equals(publisher.id) : publisher.id == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAdressLine1() {
        return adressLine1;
    }

    public void setAdressLine1(String adressLine1) {
        this.adressLine1 = adressLine1;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}
```

Error:
2021-09-03 11:34:21.454 ERROR 10844--- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: book, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(publishers)]

Comment: You have no annotation on Set<Publisher> publishers. Is it a many-to-many or a one-to-many?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164123/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-set)