# Jackson - use a JsonView within a JsonSerializer?

Tags: java, jackson

Is it possible to tell the `JsonGenerator` to serialize an object using a specific JsonView?

For example:

```
@Data
class Author {
    @JsonSerialize(using=CustomSerializer.class)
    List<Book> bestFiveBooksOfAllTime;
};
@Data
class Book extends BaseEntity
{
    @JsonView(SummaryView.class)
    private String title;
    @JsonView(SummaryView.class)
    private String author;
    private String review;
}
```

In my `CustomSerializer`, I'd like to be able to do something along the lines of:

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Author> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Author value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        for (Book book : value.getBestFiveBooksOfAllTime()) {
                    // Something like the following...
            jgen.writeObjectFieldUsingView(book.getId().toString(), book, SummaryView.class);
        }
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Ie., in the above scenario, I'd like the result to contain a map of `bestFiveBooksOfAllTime`, where the value is just the `SummaryView` of the book.

Comment: Maybe this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I ended up using -- please advise if there's a better way

```
@Override
public void serialize(Author value, JsonGenerator jgen,
        SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
    mapper.setSerializationConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(SummaryView.class));

    jgen.writeStartObject();
    for (Book book : value.getBestFiveBooksOfAllTime()) {
        jgen.writeFieldName(book.getId().toString());
        mapper.writeValue(jgen, book);
    }
    jgen.writeEndObject();
}
```

Comment: For Jackson 4, you'll need a different configuration:

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectWriter objectWriter = mapper.writer();
        if (view != null) {
            mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
            objectWriter = mapper.writerWithView(view);
        }

Comment: @adam Jackson 4?! Version 3 isn't even released yet...