# How to get custom Jackson serialization, and run it through internal Spring ObjecctMapper

Tags: java, spring, jackson

What I would like to do is serialize the `People` object having a list of only summary persons and a single person detail record.  `Person` includes nested objects like `Name` (included in summary) and `Address` (which is detail only).  And I need the internal Spring `ObjectMapper` configured to do this serialization.  I've tried to do some things with `@JsonView` and `@JsonFilter`, but not finding the right path forward.  I've also tried to provide my own custom `ObjectMapper`, and I can through its construction when my container is started, but at runtime I get errors that no filter with id "summary" has been configured.

I'm asking why the `setFilter(...)` did not seem to take effect during runtime, it's as if my customer `ObjectMapper` was constructed but not being used?
The rest of my implementation can be ignored, as I am not at all sure I am on the right path.  But, in case it helps...

- I put `@JsonFilter("summary"`) on `Person`
- I put `@JsonView(Views.Summary.class)` on select properties within `Person`
- I did not make use of Json Views, only used the annotation as a marker that my filter, which I can't get to execute, attempted to look for and then serialize the attribute if found.
- I discovered filters are not applied to List's, so...

How can I do this?

```
public class People
{
    @JsonProperty("persons")
    // A list of persons, summary info only
    private List<Person> persons;

    @JsonProperty("person")
    // A single, full detail person
    private Person person;
}


<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="myObjectMapper" />
        </bean>        
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
<bean id="myObjectMapper" class="this.that.MyObjectMapper" />

public class MyObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public MyObjectMapper() {
        super();

        Set<Class<?>> views = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        views.add(Views.Summary.class);

        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                .addFilter("summary", new FilterExceptViewFilter(views));

        setFilters(filters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was perhaps making it too hard, or at least had to think about my problem differently.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943174/jackson-use-a-jsonview-within-a-jsonserializer) was my primary inspiration.  What I needed was:

- Different serialization for my object's properties
- Different serialization implies creating a custom JsonSerializer / @JsonSerialize
- A custom serializer that chooses the correct JsonView to serialize with.

What I ended up with was fairly simple:

```
public class Views
{
    public static class Summary {}
    public static class Detail extends Summary {}
}

public class Model
{
    // Not marked with @JsonView - always serialized
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
}

public class Person extends Model
{
    @JsonView(Views.Detail.class)
    @JsonProperty("internalId")
    private String internalId;

    @JsonView(Views.Detail.class)
    @JsonProperty("tin")
    private Tin tin;

    @JsonView(Views.Summary.class)
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private Name name;
}

public class People
{
    @JsonSerialize(using = SummaryViewListSerializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("persons")
    private List<Person> persons;

    @JsonProperty("person")
    private Person person;
}

public class SummaryViewListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<Object>>
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(final List<Object> list, final JsonGenerator gen, final SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new MyObjectMapper();
        // By design, explicitly set mapper to serialize all parameters not explicitly set with @JsonView
        mapper.enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
        mapper.setSerializationConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.Summary.class));

        gen.writeStartArray();
        for (Object item : list) {
            mapper.writeValue(gen, item);
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

If I also needed to serialize `person` in summary form, I could implement a `SummaryViewSerializer` and mark the property to use that.