# @JsonView not propagated to ("nested") custom serializer

Tags: java, spring, jackson, json-view

In the unit test below there are two beans: beanA and beanB, where beanA contains a reference to beanB.

When serializing the beans providing a JSON View **with custom serializers** the custom serializer of beanB does not know about the provided JSON View, as the output of the test is:

```
{
  "clazz" : "BeanA",
  "activeView" : "ViewTest",
  "beanB" : {
    "clazz" : "BeanB",
    "activeView" : null
  }
}
```

The only way I found to propagate the activeView is: (see full source code below)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) gen.getCodec();
mapper.setConfig(provider.getConfig());
```

But the JavaDoc of setConfig() says "only use this method if you know what you are doing" - which I obviously don't do...

So my questions are:

1. Is this way of propagating the JSON View ok?
2. Is there a better way?
3. Can someone explain the default behaviour?

(there are some line commented out marked by *** - these are only interesting when playing around without custom serializers (in which case the JSON View seems to get propagated))

```
public class ViewTest {

    @Test
    public void hello() throws JsonProcessingException {

        BeanA beanA = new BeanA();
        beanA.beanB = new BeanB();

        String result = new ObjectMapper()
//            .disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION) // ***
            .writerWithView(ViewTest.class)
            .withDefaultPrettyPrinter()
            .writeValueAsString(beanA);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    @JsonSerialize(using = BeanASerializer.class)
    static public class BeanA {

//        @JsonView(ViewTest.class) // ***
        public String clazz = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

//        @JsonView(ViewTest.class) // ***
        public BeanB beanB;
    }

    @JsonSerialize(using = BeanBSerializer.class)
    static public class BeanB {

//        @JsonView(ViewTest.class) // ***
        public String clazz = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    static void writeClazzAndActiveView(String clazz, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStringField("clazz", clazz);
        gen.writeFieldName("activeView");
        if (provider.getActiveView() == null) {
            gen.writeNull();
        } else {
            gen.writeString(provider.getActiveView().getSimpleName());
        }
    }

    static class BeanASerializer extends JsonSerializer<BeanA> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(BeanA bean, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

            gen.writeStartObject();
            writeClazzAndActiveView(bean.clazz, gen, provider);

            // the only way I found to propagate the activeView:
//            ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) gen.getCodec();
//            mapper.setConfig(provider.getConfig());

            gen.writeObjectField("beanB", bean.beanB);
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }

    static class BeanBSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BeanB> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(BeanB bean, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

            gen.writeStartObject();
            writeClazzAndActiveView(bean.clazz, gen, provider);
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943174/jackson-use-a-jsonview-within-a-jsonserializer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active should be properly propagated via `SerializerProvider`. And you are right, you should not set (nor have to set) view that way -- it is not thread-safe, for one, and all configuration of `ObjectMapper` is to be done before any and all use
(`ObjectReader` and `ObjectWriter` allow per-call changes via various factory methods).

Why this is happening is unclear: I think filing a bug with version info and full reproduction (if there's more to it than code) makes sense.

Comment: Thanks & done: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2193