# Jackson - custom serializer that overrides only specific fields

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I know how to use a custom serializer in Jackson (by extending `JsonSerializer`), but I want the default serializer to work for all fields, except for just 1 field, which I want to override using the custom serializer.

Annotations are not an option, because I am serializing a generated class (from Thrift).

How do I specify only certain fields to be overridden when writing a custom jackson serializer?

*Update:*

Here's the class I want to serialize:

```
class Student {
    int age;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    double average;
    int numSubjects

    // .. more such properties ...
}
```

The above class has many properies, most of which use native types. I want to just override a few properties in the custom serializer and let Jackson deal with the rest as usual. For e.g. I just want to convert the "age" field to a custom output.

Comment: which jackson version is used

Comment: Have look to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson) you may get some idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same issue, and I solved it with [CustomSerializerFactory](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ser/CustomSerializerFactory.html).

This approach allows you to ignore some specific field for either for all objects, or for specific types.

```
public class EntityCustomSerializationFactory extends CustomSerializerFactory {

    //ignored fields
    private static final Set<String> IGNORED_FIELDS = new HashSet<String>(
            Arrays.asList(
                    "class",
                    "value",
                    "some"
            )
    );


    public EntityCustomSerializationFactory() {
        super();
    }

    public EntityCustomSerializationFactory(Config config) {
        super(config);
    }

    @Override
    protected void processViews(SerializationConfig config, BeanSerializerBuilder builder) {
        super.processViews(config, builder);

        //ignore fields only for concrete class
        //note, that you can avoid or change this check
        if (builder.getBeanDescription().getBeanClass().equals(Entity.class)){
            //get original writer
            List<BeanPropertyWriter> originalWriters = builder.getProperties();

            //create actual writers
            List<BeanPropertyWriter> writers = new ArrayList<BeanPropertyWriter>();

            for (BeanPropertyWriter writer: originalWriters){
                String propName = writer.getName();

                //if it isn't ignored field, add to actual writers list
                if (!IGNORED_FIELDS.contains(propName)){
                    writers.add(writer);
                }
            }

            builder.setProperties(writers);
        }

    }
}
```

And afterwards you can use it something like the following:

```
objectMapper.setSerializerFactory(new EntityCustomSerializationFactory());
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Entity());//response will be without ignored fields
```

Comment: The code in its original version does not work anymore. You need to extent `BeanSerializerFactory` instead of `CustomSerializerFactory` and set the serializer factory like this:  `objectMapper.setSerializerFactory(new EntityCustomSerializationFactory((BeanSerializerFactory) objectMapper.getSerializerFactory()));`

Answer (score 16):

Assuming your Target class is

```
public class Student {
    int age;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    double average;
    int numSubjects;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    public void setAverage(double average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

    public int getNumSubjects() {
        return numSubjects;
    }

    public void setNumSubjects(int numSubjects) {
        this.numSubjects = numSubjects;
    }

}
```

You need to write a custom serializer as given below

```
public class MyCustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Student> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Student value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        if (value != null) {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeStringField("age", "Age: " + value.getAge()); //Here a custom way to render age field is used
            jgen.writeStringField("firstName", value.getFirstName());
            jgen.writeStringField("lastName", value.getLastName());
            jgen.writeNumberField("average", value.getAverage());
            jgen.writeNumberField("numSubjects", value.getNumSubjects());
            //Write other properties
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }

}
```

then add it to the ObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("custom",
        Version.unknownVersion());
module.addSerializer(Student.class, new MyCustomSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

then use it like

```
Student s = new Student();
s.setAge(2);
s.setAverage(3.4);
s.setFirstName("first");
s.setLastName("last");
s.setNumSubjects(3);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(sw, s);
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

It will produce a o/p like

> {"age":"Age:
>   2","firstName":"first","lastName":"last","average":3.4,"numSubjects":3}

Comment: Let's say I define a custom serializer for class T which has 3 fields and I only do one write() in my serializer (for the only field which I want to override), will the other 2 fields be serialzed using defaults?

Comment: yes, but all the fields of the overridden type will use the custom serializer

Comment: Got it - in my case I have a class with fields having native types.. E.g. int count, long total etc. Looks like I can't use this approach in that case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26088/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-jeffreyveon)

Answer (score 15):

Just because you can not modify classes DOES NOT mean you could not use annotations: just use mix-in annotations. See [this](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html) blog entry for example (or google for more with "jackson mixin annotations") for how to use this.

I have specifically used Jackson with protobuf- and thrift-generated classes, and they work pretty well. For earlier Thrift versions, I had to disable discovery of "is-setters", methods Thrift generates to see if a specific property has been explicitly set, but otherwise things worked fine.

Comment: That looks pretty neat - thanks. I will try this approach too.

Comment: Yeah it's good to know options, some work better in some, others in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to pollute your model with annotations, you could use mixins.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.setMixInAnnotation(Student.class, StudentMixin.class);
mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

And you want to override id field for example:

```
public abstract class StudentMixin {
    @JsonSerialize(using = StudentIdSerializer.class)
    public String id;
}
```

Do whatever you need with the field:

```
public class StudentIdSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Integer integer, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(String.valueOf(integer * 2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @JsonView we can decide fields of model classes to serialize which satisfy the minimal criteria ( we have to define the criteria) like we can have one core class with 10 properties but only 5 properties can be serialize which are needful for client only

Define our Views by simply creating following class:

```
public class Views
{
    static class Android{};
    static class IOS{};
    static class Web{};
}
```

Annotated model class with views:

```
public class Demo 
{
    public Demo() 
    {
    }

@JsonView(Views.IOS.class)
private String iosField;

@JsonView(Views.Android.class)
private String androidField;

@JsonView(Views.Web.class)
private String webField;

 // getters/setters
...
..
}
```

Now we have to write custom json converter by simply extending HttpMessageConverter class from spring as:

```
    public class CustomJacksonConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<Object> 
    {
    public CustomJacksonConverter() 
        {
            super();
        //this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.ClientView.class));
        this.delegate.getObjectMapper().configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
        this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

    }

    // a real message converter that will respond to methods and do the actual work
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter delegate = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return delegate.canRead(clazz, mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return delegate.canWrite(clazz, mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        return delegate.getSupportedMediaTypes();
    }

    @Override
    public Object read(Class<? extends Object> clazz,
            HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException,
            HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        return delegate.read(clazz, inputMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Object obj, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException 
    {
        synchronized(this) 
        {
            String userAgent = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getHeader("userAgent");
            if ( userAgent != null ) 
            {
                switch (userAgent) 
                {
                case "IOS" :
                    this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.IOS.class));
                    break;
                case "Android" :
                    this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.Android.class));
                    break;
                case "Web" :
                    this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView( Views.Web.class));
                    break;
                default:
                    this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView( null ));
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // reset to default view
                this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView( null ));
            }
            delegate.write(obj, contentType, outputMessage);
        }
    }

}
```

Now there is need to tell spring to use this custom json convert by simply putting this in dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
            <bean id="jsonConverter" class="com.mactores.org.CustomJacksonConverter" >
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

That's how you will able to decide which fields to get serialize.

Thanx