# Mixing Spring MVC + Spring Data Rest results in odd MVC responses

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a two JPA entities, one with a SDR exported repository, and another with a Spring MVC controller, and a non-exported repository.

The MVC exposed entity has a reference to the SDR managed entity.  See below for code reference.

The problem comes into play when retrieving a `User` from the `UserController`.  The SDR managed entity won't serialize, and it seems that Spring may be trying to use HATEOAS refs in the response.

Here's what a `GET` for a fully populated `User` looks like:

```
{
  "username": "foo@gmail.com",
  "enabled": true,
  "roles": [
    {
      "role": "ROLE_USER",
      "content": [],
      "links": [] // why the content and links?
    }
    // no places?
  ]
}
```

How do I plainly return the `User` entity from my Controller with the embedded SDR managed Entity?

***Spring MVC Managed***

*Entity*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    // UID

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password_hash")
    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    private String passwordHash;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean enabled;

    // No Repository
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NotEmpty
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>();

    // The SDR Managed Entity
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_place", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "users_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "place_id")})
    private Set<Place> places = new HashSet<>();

    // getters and setters
}
```

*Repo*

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
    // Query Methods
}
```

*Controller*

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    // backed by UserRepository
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/users/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUser(@PathVariable String username) {
        return userService.getByUsername(username);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserCreateView user) {
        return userService.create(user);
    }

    // Other MVC Methods
}
```

***SDR Managed***

*Entity*

```
@Entity
public class Place implements Serializable {

    // UID

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String handle;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_info_id")
    private ContactInfo contactInfo;

    // getters and setters
}
```

*Repo*

```
public interface PlaceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Place, Long> {
    // Query Methods
}
```

Comment: I assume you do have @Repository annotation for PlaceRepository - just didn't post it here? Could you add the text of the exception as well?

Comment: @lenach87 - SDR doesn't require the `@Repository` annotation unless you need to further configure it.  There is also no Exception, just the lack of serialization.

Comment: Maybe the problem with your JPA implementation?   If you are using Hibernate, it can make eager load of  only ONE bag.  you can create a custom query to force it to load eagerly, or simply call accessor of the property before sending it as a response (this will force hibernate to load the property bag).

Comment: Maybe check this, assuming that you use jackson for serialization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580856/jackson-list-serialization-nested-lists

Comment: Can you add your repository configuration?  Is it possible that there are two entityManagers handling these repositories and one cannot see the entities in the other?

Comment: @woemler That's possible.  Let me get a dump from `/beans` and see.  I don't define any myself.

Comment: @BrandonV: It should be pretty easy to write a test to fetch some `User` records and see if the `Place` records populate, since it is set to eager fetching.

Comment: @woemler - I take back my comment.  I actually already do know that Place entities are being populated within the User entity.  They just won't serialize.  I'm now wondering if it's an issue with not using `@RepositoryRestController` as specified in the SDR docs.  Though I'm not sure why.

Comment: have you tried to deserialize explicitly (just to check if its called at all)? Normally your code (if all getters are there) should work, i feel. In the end you serialize Pojos, don't you? The annotations shouldnt have any effects on that.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell: Spring Data REST and Spring HATEOAS hijack the ObjectMapper and want to represent relationships between resources as *links* rather than embedding the resource.

Take an entity with a one to one relationship with another entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @OneToOne private Address address;
}
```

SDR/HATEOAS will return address as a link:

```
{
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "_links": {
        "self": { "href": "http://localhost:8080/persons/123123123" },
        "address": { "href": "http://localhost:8080/addresses/9127391273" }
    }
}
```

The default format can change depending on what you have on your classpath.   I believe this is HAL in my example which is the default when you've included SDR and HATEOAS.  *It may be different but similar depending on said config*.

Spring will do this when `Address` is managed by SDR.  If it were not managed by SDR at all it would include the entire address object in the response.  I suspect that alone explains the behavior you're seeing.

**Roles**

You haven't included information on `UserRole` but based on your code it appears that is likely not managed outside of `User` and therefore doesn't have a Spring Data repository registered.  If this is the case that's why it's getting embedded -- there's no other repository to 'link' to.

The `content` and `links` under roles looks like Spring trying to serialize it like a `Page`.  Generally `content` will have an array of resources and `links` will have the links such as 'self' or links to other resources.  I'm not sure what's causing that.

**Place**

Place has it's own Spring Data repository so it's going to be treated as a managed entity and linked to rather than embedded.  I suspect what you're looking for is a projection.  Checkout the Spring [documentation on projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts).  It would look something like this:

```
@Projection(name = "embedPlaces", types = { User.class })
interface EmbedPlaces {
    String getUsername();
    boolean isEnabled();
    Set<Place> getPlaces();
}
```

That *should* serialize the username, enabled and roles and omit everything else.  I've not personally used projections yet so I can't vouch for how well it works but this is the solution in the documentation.

EDIT: While we're at it please note that this applies to creating or updating resources as well.  Spring will expect the resource as a URL.  So taking the Person/Address example if I were creating a new person my body might look like:

```
{
    "firstName": "New",
    "lastName": "Person",
    "address": "http://localhost:8080/addresses/1290312039123"
}
```

It's rather easy to forget these things as the vast, vast, vast, vast, vast majority of "REST" APIs are not REST and SDR/HATEOAS take an opinionated view of REST (e.g. that it should be REST, for one).

Answer (score -1):

You can very well use a @ResponseEntity in your Controller and then set User Object in the ResponseEntity.

Please see example below:

```
ResponseEntity<User> respEntity = new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Then on the client side you can call, `restTemplate.getForEntity`

Please see restTemplate documentation below:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this helps me at all.