# RestTemplate returning null when serialized to POJO

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I was following the start-up guide of at spring website https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/.

I am not following the exact tutorial in the sense that I am using another endpoint: http://www.omdbapi.com?s=rush.

I am having an issue with JSON conversion to POJO. I am not getting any error or exceptions. Could someone point out where am I going wrong?

You can find the complete code [here](https://github.com/amriteyapandey/java-rest-consumption)

Here are my POJOs:

```
package com.sample.restapi.model;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class SearchResponse {

    private List<Search> search;

    private String totalResults;

    private String response;

    public SearchResponse() {

    }

    public List<Search> getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(List<Search> search) {
        this.search = search;
    }

    public String getTotalResults() {
        return totalResults;
    }

    public void setTotalResults(String totalResults) {
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SearchResponse [search=" + search + ", totalResults=" + totalResults + ", response=" + response + "]";
    }

}
```

Here is the Search.java

```
package com.sample.restapi.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Search {

    private String title;

    private String year;

    private String imdbID;

    private String type;

    private String poster;

    public Search() {

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getImdbID() {
        return imdbID;
    }

    public void setImdbID(String imdbID) {
        this.imdbID = imdbID;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getPoster() {
        return poster;
    }

    public void setPoster(String poster) {
        this.poster = poster;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Search [title=" + title + ", year=" + year + ", imdbID=" + imdbID + ", type=" + type + ", poster="
                + poster + "]";
    }
}
```

Here is the driver class.

```
package com.sample.restapi;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.sample.restapi.model.SearchResponse;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumerApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        SearchResponse searchResponse = restTemplate.getForObject("http://www.omdbapi.com?s=rush", SearchResponse.class);

        log.info(searchResponse.toString());
    }
}
```

The console output is :

```
14:34:12.941 [main] INFO com.sample.restapi.ConsumerApplication - SearchResponse [search=null, totalResults=344, response=null]
```

Comment: What exactly is giving null? I suspect you mean that the List<Search> is null. In that case possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580856/jackson-list-serialization-nested-lists

Comment: @Redlab I just made an edit specifying the console output I am getting. I guess you cannot say it's duplicate because I am not able to understand how is RestTemplate processing the consumed API and converting to my POJO.

Comment: you are right it's not a duplicate. see my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing correct identifiers for the properties in the json, there are differences in the response and your classes in the Capital and lower case letters. Use @JsonProperty in your classes.

```
@JsonProperty("Search")
private List<Search> search = new ArrayList<Search>();

private String totalResults;
@JsonProperty("Response")
private String response;
```

you should also add @JsonProperty annotations in the Search class.

Comment: I have a question. Why was I getting data for `totalResults` field then?

Comment: totalResults case is same as json response

Comment: Also, why is that in the guideline they're not using the annotion @JsonProperty and it is still working?

Comment: as @shi said, totalResult in class is same charaters in the json. If you'd wan tto add an annotation it should be @JsonProperty("totalResults").