# How to control Jackson serialization of a library class

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a class (let us call it a `Piece`) containing a member of type `com.jme3.math.ColorRGBA`. With a default Jackson serialization the member is serialized not only as its members `r`, `g`, `b` and `a`, but then also using getters like `getAlpha`.

As this is obviously redundant, I would like to control the serialization and to serialize only those primary members. Are there some annotations that I can write to my class to control serialization of members with types not under my control, or some custom serializers for them?

I can probably write a custom serializer for the `Piece` class, though other than `ColorRGBA` serializer being too verbose, default serialization works fine for me for all other properties of `Piece`, therefore I would like to customize as little of it as possible.

I do not want to modify `jme3` library source, the solution should be implemented outside of the `ColorRGBA` class.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378853/jackson-custom-serializer-that-overrides-only-specific-fields?rq=1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a *mixin* to make sure that the class is serialized as per your needs. Consider the following:

```
// The source class (where you do not own the source code)
public class ColorRGBA {
    public float a; // <-- Want to skip this one
    public float b;
    public float g;
    public float r;
}
```

Then, create the mixin where you ignore the `a` property.

```
// Create a mixin where you ignore the "a" property
@JsonIgnoreProperties("a")
public abstract class RGBMixin {
    // Other settings if required such as @JsonProperty on abstract methods.
}
```

Lastly, configure your mapper with the mixin:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(ColorRGBA.class, RGBMixin.class);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new ColorRGBA()));
```

The output will be:

> {"b":0.0,"g":0.0,"r":0.0}

Note that the method `ObjectMapper.addMixInAnnotations` is deprecated from Jackson 2.5 and should be replaced with the more fluent version:

```
mapper.addMixIn(ColorRGBA.class, RGBMixin.class);
```

The JavaDocs can be [found here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#addMixIn%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Looks promising, however some more effort will be needed, as with recent Jackson `addMixInAnnotations` is deprecated in `ObjectMapper` and one needs to use a [feature module](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Comment: @Suma, you can simply replace the `addMixInAnnotations` with a call to `addMixIn`, that will do the trick (answer updated to reflect Jackson 2.5)

Comment: It also appears that, even with Jackson 2.8, an alternative implementation of the `RGBMixin` class with the use of `@JsonIngore` annotation doesn't work for some reason e.g. `public abstract class RGBMixin { @JsonIgnore String a; }`. I'm not sure whether it's a libray bug or intended as I couldn't find any documentation that clearly explains this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

## Option A

**If** you control the source of the class, can put this above class:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class ColorRGBA {
```

## Option B

Otherwise you can set up an object mapper to ignore getters:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));

mapper.writeValue(stream, yourObject);
```

## Option C

For more complicated requirements, you can write your own [VisibilityChecker](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/introspect/VisibilityChecker.html) implementation.

Comment: No, I do not have any control over com.jme3.math, it is an external library.

Comment: @Suma I know, that's more for other visitors. For you, use option b.

Comment: Thanks, look viable at first, but that would also modify behaviour for all other classes? For some classes getters / setters may be needed. The ideal solution should affect only my ColorRGBA member and nothing else (or at most all members of ColorRGBA type).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write a custom serializer for the member only, using annotation for the member like this:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomColorRGBASerializer.class)
ColorRGBA color;
```

See also [this answer about how to custom-serialize a Date field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10835504/16673).