# Jackson JSON help (Serializer)

Tags: json, jackson

I am using jackson 1.9.11.

I need to create a JSON as follows :

```
"items": [
{
"batch": "sectionA",
"id": "section1",
"full": "N",
"numStudents": 2,
"students": [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "married": "Y"

    },
    {
        "name": "Mary",
        "married": "N"
    }
]
},
{
"batch": "sectionB",
"id": "section2",
"full": "Y",
"numStudents": 3,
"students": [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "married": "Y"

    },
    {
        "name": "Mary",
        "married": "N"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sam",
        "married": "N"
    }
]
}

]
```

I have a HashMap with : `"items" = List<Batch>`

Each Batch the following variables : batch,`List<Students>`

I need to evaluate : "full" based on some values in a HashMap (this Map gets created using some helper classes).

"numStudents" is `List<Students>.size()`

"id" is "section" appended with the index of this Batch in `List<Batch>`

Now the problem is that i cannot modify these classes as they are part of a library. How do i go about solving this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goals using two ways: simple and complex.

> Simple:

You can create new POJO classes with fields which you need. After that, you have to convert your library objects into new into new POJO objects and, finally, serialize it using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.

> Complex:

You can write new serializer/deserializer for your library classes, but this solution is much complicated.

Helpful links:

- [How do I use a custom Serializer with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson)
- [Using Custom Serializers with Jackson](http://techtraits.com/Programming/2011/11/20/using-custom-serializers-with-jackson/)
- [Jackson How-To: Custom Serializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers)