# Ninja Framework Return JSON in custom format

Tags: java, json, ninjaframework

How do we return JSON of custom format while returning JSON in NINJA FRAMEWORK controller.

```
    return Results.json().render(MyPOJO);
```

MyPOJO class

```
    @Entity
    public class MyPOJO {
       private String Name;
       private String Value;

       public String getName() {
           return Name;
       }
       public void setName(String Name) {
           this.Name = Name;
       }
       public String getValue() {
           return Value;
       }
       public void setValue(String Value) {
           this.Value = Value;
       }
  }
```

Current JSON Output

```
  [{"Name":"Person1", "Value":"Value1"}, {"Name":"Person2", "Value":"Value2"}]
```

Custom JSON Output (Required)

```
  [{"1":"Person1", "2":"Value1"}, {"1":"Person2", "2":"Value2"}]
```

Comment: And why do you need this? The json `[` character already indicates that inside those is an array, so you just need to get the index of it. Plus, doing this would turn your json result in an invalid json object which can bring problems to you in the future

Comment: Dear Jorge, the required output is the standard json input for datatables (www.datatables.net). Moreover, removing the key and replacing with an index greatly reduces my network usage size when I fetch huge number of records. Also I verified my output through jsonlint.com, the format is correct and valid.

Comment: Sorry, I was missreading your json output. I was reading as `{"1":"Name":"Person1", "2":"Value":"Value1"}` as if the "1" means the index of that data. Yes, you are right this is a valid Json object. What you will have to do in that case is to use the ObjectMapper and implement a CustomSerializer. As Ninja FrameWork uses Jackson. See it here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureModules

Comment: See this thread, maybe it can be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jorge is right - Ninja just uses Jackson to serialize stuff - you can use all goodies of Jackson to customize parsing and rendering of your entities.

In your case the solution is simple. Just use @JsonProperty like that:

```
@Entity
public class MyPOJO {
   private String Name;
   private String Value;

   @JsonProperty("1")
   public String getName() {
       return Name;
   }
   public void setName(String Name) {
       this.Name = Name;
   }

   @JsonProperty("2")
   public String getValue() {
       return Value;
   }
   public void setValue(String Value) {
       this.Value = Value;
   }
```

}