# Jersey Rest - JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class ]

Tags: java, json, api, rest, jersey

I created a REST API using jax-rs and jersey. I want to return an object in JSON format from an external library in my REST API. However this object has **no default constructor** which causes the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class ....EncryptionToken]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
```

What is the best way to return this object through a REST API?

This is my REST API implementation:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public javax.ws.rs.core.Response get( //
            @QueryParam("etkIdentifierType") String etkIdentifierType, //
            @QueryParam("etkIdentifierValue") String etkIdentifierValue, //
            @QueryParam("applicationId") String applicationId) {
    LOG.info("GET Request: Lookup encryption token for etkIdentifierType [" + etkIdentifierType + "], etkIdentifierValue [" + etkIdentifierValue + "] and applicationId [" + applicationId + "]");
    final EncryptionToken token = etkService.getETK(etkIdentifierType, etkIdentifierValue, applicationId);
    return Response.ok(token).build();
}
```

The Encryption class comes from an external library that I can't modify. I first tried to construct an own object with the same variables and return this, but not all the getter methods are public.

This is the EncryptionToken class:

```
package ...;

public class EncryptionToken {
    private java.security.cert.X509Certificate encrCert;
    private byte[] encoded;
    private java.security.cert.X509Certificate authCert;
    private java.security.cert.X509Certificate etkRaCert;
    private java.util.List<java.security.cert.X509Certificate> caCertChain;

    EncryptionToken(byte[] encoded, java.security.cert.X509Certificate encrCert, java.security.cert.X509Certificate authCert, java.util.List<java.security.cert.X509Certificate> caCertChain, java.security.cert.X509Certificate etkRaCert) { /* compiled code */ }

    public final byte[] getEncoded() { /* compiled code */ }

    public final byte[] getBase64Encoded() { /* compiled code */ }

    public final java.security.cert.X509Certificate getCertificate() { /* compiled code */ }

    public final java.security.cert.X509Certificate getAuthenticationCertificate() { /* compiled code */ }

    java.util.List<java.security.cert.X509Certificate> getCaCertChain() { /* compiled code */ }

    java.security.cert.X509Certificate getEtkRaCert() { /* compiled code */   }
}
```

**EDIT**: I think for my case I need a deserializer. The code is failing on the following line:

```
final EncryptionToken encryptionToken = response.getEntity(EncryptionToken.class);
```

But since I cant instantiate an EncryptionToken (no default constructor and available constructor is nog public) I don't know how to fix this...

Comment: Add a default (non-arguments) constructor to EncryptionToken. Maybe Jackson create an empty instance and then put attributes by getters/setters

Comment: @bigdestroyer that was my first idea, but unfortunately I don't have access to the EncryptionToken class since it's located in an external jar from which I can't modify the content. My other idea was to extend this class, but the constructor is package protected. Third solution would be to create a new class with the same variables and pass this, but since not all getters are public and other methods I use use the EncryptionToken object, I can't write a decent mapper between the objects...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom `JsonSerializer` object and register it into Jackson context.

```
public class EncryptionTokenSerializer extends JsonSerializer<EncryptionToken> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(EncryptionToken value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeBinaryField("encoded", value.getEncoded());
        jgen.writeBinaryField("base64Encoded", value.getBase64Encoded());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

If you want to know how to register serializer in the context check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20530302/3017003)

Comment: Thanks for your example. This is very promising. However, how do you register this custom serializer into your jackson context? I would annotate the class with `@JsonSerialize(using = EncryptionTokenSerializer.class)` but since I don't have access to the EncryptionToken class, I can't do this...

Comment: I managed to pass by the EncryptionTokenSerializer (in debug mode), but unfortuanately I still receive the complaint that a default constructor is missing for the EncryptionToken class... `com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class be.fgov.ehealth.etee.crypto.encrypt.EncryptionToken]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@77da01; line: 1, column: 2]`

Answer (score 0):

Hey I tried your code on my machine. I didn't have any problem executing it.
It's giving me proper result.
Can you provide implementation of method 'etkService.getETK()' and the declaration & definition of 'etkService'. There may be some problem due to that.

final EncryptionToken token = etkService.getETK(etkIdentifierType, etkIdentifierValue, applicationId);

And it is not necessary to provide the deserializer for your POJO