# Naming a json property after a variable value

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

I am using a jackson provider for my rest service:

```
<jaxrs:server id="services" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <bean class="..."/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I have this class:

```
public class Response {
    private Date myDate;
    private DataObject data; //data related to that date
}
```

and this method returning a json:

```
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getResp(){
       Response r = ...
       return r;
}
```

This translates in the following json object

```
{
   "myDate":"20150730",
   "data":{
         "p1":"v1",
         "p2":"v2"
          }
}
```

Is it possible to obtain something like this, instead:

```
"20150730":{
         "p1":"v1",
         "p2":"v2"
          }
```

in other words to have the **myDate** content to be the actual json property and **data** content to be the json value?

Answer (score 2):

You could [write your own serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7161638/2587435). For example

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;

public class ResponseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Response> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Response resp, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) 
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jg.writeStartObject();
        String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(resp.myDate);
        jg.writeObjectField(dateString, resp.data);
        jg.writeEndObject();
    } 
}
```

I don't know what your `Date` object is. I assumed it `java.util.Date` so I just created a formatter. All this serializer does is add the date string as the key and `ObjectData` and the value.

Then you need to register the serializer with the `ObjectMapper`. You can do that in a `ContextResolver` (which is a JAX-RS way to configure the mapper)

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>{

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule(
                "ResponseModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null)
        );
        module.addSerializer(Response.class, new ResponseSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Then just register the `ObjectMapperContextResolver` like you would any other provider in your xml config.