# No Converter Found Error when using Custom JsonSerializer

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson

In a Spring application I want to use my own JsonSerializer  with a RestController. My JsonSerializer is registered in a Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder. So far so good, but when I annotate the respective fields with @JsonSerialize Spring MVC complains that there is no converter found for my class. Here is the code:

```
public class DurationAsHourSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Duration>{
    @Override
    public void serialize(Duration value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            gen.writeNumber(value.toHours());

    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder b = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Duration.class, new DurationAsHourSerializer());
        b.modulesToInstall(module);
        return b;
    }
}

@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class Order {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotNull
    private String customerId;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private ZonedDateTime validFrom;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private ZonedDateTime validTo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonSerialize(as=DurationAsHourSerializer.class)
    private Duration maxDuration;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonSerialize(as=DurationAsHourSerializer.class)
    private Duration actDuration;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("order")
public class OrderController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createOrder(@RequestBody @Valid Order order) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/" + order.getId()).build().toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Order getExample() {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setMaxDuration(Duration.ofHours(10));
        return order;
    }
}
```

When I send a request to getExample(), I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return
>   value of type: class com.sap.sptutorial.rest.Order    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:178)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

Why can't the Converter use my serializer, or why does my serializer make the otherwise existing converter unavailable?

PS: This is a follow up to [How do I use a custom Serializer with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson) where I tried to use a Field Formatter for the same job, and learned that Formatters are not used for the Jackson Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

It reason behind this could be, because there is already another object of Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder constructed by Spring and it is still using it.

You need to make sure you make this @Bean as the default to be used by spring or use @PostConstruct rather that @Bean to modify the same instance of Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder initialized by Spring

```
@Autowired
private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder;
............

@PostConstruct
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder b = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Duration.class, new DurationAsHourSerializer());
    b.modulesToInstall(module);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: No. If I remove the JsonSerialize annotation from the Duration typed fields the converter is found! The serializer seems to be registered correctly. But its use somehow makes the otherwise used converter unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that I used the wrong attribute with the @JsonSerialize annotation. Instead of `@JsonSerialize(as=DurationAsHourSerializer.class)` you have to declare the serializer to use with `@JsonSerialize(using=DurationAsHourSerializer.class)`