# How to pass context through custom JsonSerializer? (Java, ObjectMapper)

Tags: java, jackson

I have custom JsonSerializer:

```
new JsonSerializer<T>() {
    @Override
    public void serialize(T instance, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        try {
            instance = someFunction(instance);
            SerializableString serializableString = new SerializedString(defaultMapper.writeValueAsString(instance));
            gen.writeRawValue(serializableString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For my pourpuses, i need a way to pass `gen.getOutputContext()` to the `defaultMapper.writeValueAsString(instance)`. Is there a way to achieve this? Or am I using the ObjectMapper the wrong way? Thank you for any insight.

EDIT: the `defaultMapper` is of type `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin am using jackson ObjectMapper to create bases for .csv file for translating data ... i have special wrapper for texts that are visible to end users, so i can create rows using custom serialiser (with key, oldValue, newValue (to be edited), but i need "path" for orientation and integration of translations into data mode)l. However some other classes require their own custom serializer (similar to one provided in question) and i loose context - as a result i only get "path" from the last custom-serialized node, not from root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ObjectMapper` actually have exactly the method i needed built in - `ObjectMapper.writeValue(JsonGenerator, T)`. Modified (and functional) code from my question:

```
new JsonSerializer<T>() {
    @Override
    public void serialize(T instance, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        try {
            instance = someFunction(instance);
            defaultMapper.writeValue(gen, instance)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here to help do my best to help you out!

I don't have the java environment setup, but an example using the Jackson JSON package is here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Let me know if this helps!

Based on the tutorial, depending how your object is set up you can **use the Object Mapper Object using the "writeVaueAsString(object o) with the method "writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter() method to get a readable JSON String**

However this isn't a "custom" Serializer/Deserializer.

Would this solution work for you?

Comment: This stackoverflow thread might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however my problem is not that the mapper is not working - i am using custom serializers to do some data transformation and i need to know the "path" of certain objects (sets of keys from root to the object). However some of the other objects require custom serialization and therefore when i need to acces the "path" (via `gen.getOutputContext()`), all i get is "path" from the last custom serialized object, not from the root. Therefore i am looking for a way to pass `gen.getOutputContext()` to my `default mapper` to get around this.