# Jackson JSON pointer format serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
class SubClass {
    private String a1;    
    private String a2; 
}

class B {    
    private String b1;    
    private Subclass subclass;  
}
```

Can Jackson serialize the above 'class B' to a JSON which looks like:

```
{
   "/B/b1": "xxxxx",
   "/B/subclass/a1": "xxxxxx",
   "/B/subclass/a2": "xxxxxx"
}
```

i.e. all flattened to JSON pointer instead of the traditional tree structure.

Comment: Nope. Jackson offers something, and that's not it. I am not aware of some library that offers a kind of serialization like that, but there may be some.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can write [a custom serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson) for `Subclass` type but what you want is not among [existing serialization features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-features).