# How to configure jackson for convert Enum to JSON?

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, jackson, jackson-databind

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter    
public enum MemberType {
    INTERN("name_intern", 1),
    EMPLOYEE("name_employee", 10);

    private String name;
    private int workingMonth;
}
```

Here is my enum. I want to convert `Enum` class to `JSON` string with some constraint.

1. I want to MemberType has no dependency with Jackson
2. I want to convert `MemberType.INTERN` to `{id:INTERN, name:"name_intern", workingMonth:10}`.
3. I have lots of Enums want to convert like above. And Their number of property is different each other.
4. I want resolve this problem through just one global configuration.
5. I don't want to use explicit java reflection.

Is there a solution that meets the above constraints?

Comment: I think you're better of using constants instead of `enum` given all your constraints.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `@JsonFormat` annotation like this:

```
 @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
 public enum MemberType { ... }
```

or you can use `@JsonValue` annotation like this:

```
public enum MemberType {
        [...]

@JsonValue
public String getName() {
 return name;
}
```

}

or maybe a `CustomSerializer` for Enum, you can find more details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums).

Answer (score 2):

If you implement JsonSerializer,you can custom serialization.

An example is shown below.

```
@JsonComponent
public final class MediaTypeJsonComponent {
    public static class Serializer extends JsonSerializer<MemberType> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(MemberType value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField("id", value.name());
            gen.writeNumberField("workingMonth", value.getWorkingMonth());
            gen.writeStringField("name", value.getName());
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
    //
    // If you need,write code.
    //public static class Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Customer> {
    //}
}
```

Another way is to implement JsonSerialize.

If you want more information, you should refer to:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jackson/JsonComponent.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization
- [How do I use a custom Serializer with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson)
- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums