# Convert Dataframe Dataset<Row> to JSON Format of String Data Type for particular Columns and convert the JSON String back to Dataframe

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataframe. I need to call a Rest API for each record.

Lets say the Dataframe looks like:

```
|----|-------------|-----|---------|
|UUID|PID          |DEVID|FIRSTNAME|
|----|-------------|-----|---------|
|1111|1234567891011|ABC11|JOHN     |
|2222|9876543256827|ABC22|HARRY    |
|----|-------------|-----|---------|
```

The JSON request string for first row should look like(Note: the json is created on 2 columns, not all), as the Rest API to be called requires the input in this format:

```
{"applicationInfo": {"appId": "ec78fef4-92b9-3b1b-a68d-c45376b6977a"}, "requestData": [{"secureData": "JOHN", "secureDataType": "FIRSTNAME", "index": 1 }, {"secureData": "1234567891011", "secureDataType": "PID", "index": 2 } ] }
```

The value of index key has to be generted on the fly, using an incremental counter for each row.

Then, i need to call the Rest API sending the above JSON as a string param.

The response from the API after encryption will look like:

```
{"responseData":[{"resultCode":"00","secureData":"63ygdydshbhgvdyw3et7edgu","secureDataType":"FIRSTNAME","index":1},{"resultCode":"00","secureData":"HKJJBJHVHG66456456FXXFFCGF","secureDataType":"PID","index":2}],"responseCode":"00","responseMessage":"SUCCESS","resultCounts":{"totalCount":2,"successCount":2,"failedCount":0}}
```

Then I need to read the above response and create a dataframe which should look like:

```
|----|--------------------------|-----|------------------------|
|UUID|PID                       |DEVID|FIRSTNAME               |
|----|--------------------------|-----|------------------------|
|1111|HKJJBJHVHG66456456FXXFFCGF|ABC11|63ygdydshbhgvdyw3et7edgu|
|----|--------------------------|-----|------------------------|
```

If i convert the initial input dataframe toJSON().collectAsList(), then it looks like:

```
[{"UUID":"1111","PID":"1234567891011","DEVID":"ABC11","FIRSTNAME":"JOHN"}, {"UUID":"2222","PID":"9876543256827","DEVID":"ABC22","FIRSTNAME":"HARRY"}]
```

But this doesnt work as the Rest API requires its input in a certain format, mentioned above.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

For the above, I assume that the data set has been partitioned across the number of Spark workers and it is a generic data set of Row (data frame), then the below mechanism can be employed.

1. Define a class with the required attributes as a data container
2. Take the data set content as a List (takeAsList method if data set, [refer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#takeAsList-int-))
3. Create and populate the objects of your data container (and store in such a way to identify them later, you shall have to repopulate them with decrypted data)
4. Serialize the list into a JSON array with Jackson ([refer](https://makeinjava.com/convert-array-objects-json-jackson-objectmapper/))
   Step 4 & 5 can be combined with Jackson custom serializer [refer example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson)
5. Make the REST call and repopulate the data container objects (after deserializing the response with Jackson)
6. Create a data frame ([an example](http://timepasstechies.com/create-spark-dataframe-java-list/))
7. Process the data frame (dataset of rows)

NOTE: The JSON structure you have provided seems not to be correct, JSON array is [{},{},{}]

---

In your case, given the format of the request JSON, direct conversion of rows will not work, as mentioned in point 1, make a set of model classes, you could consider the below model classes.

```
package org.test.json;

import java.util.List;

public class RequestModel {

protected ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
protected List<RequestData> requestData;

public ApplicationInfo getApplicationInfo() {return applicationInfo;}
public void setApplicationInfo(ApplicationInfo applicationInfo) {this.applicationInfo = applicationInfo;}

public List<RequestData> getRequestData() {return requestData;}
public void setRequestData(List<RequestData> requestData) {this.requestData = requestData;}

}//class closing




package org.test.json;

public class ApplicationInfo {

protected String appId;

public String getAppId() {return appId;}
public void setAppId(String appId) {this.appId = appId;}

}//class closing




package org.test.json;

public class RequestData {

protected String secureData;
protected String secureDataType;
protected int index;

public String getSecureData() {return secureData;}
public void setSecureData(String secureData) {this.secureData = secureData;}

public String getSecureDataType() {return secureDataType;}
public void setSecureDataType(String secureDataType) {this.secureDataType = secureDataType;}

public int getIndex() {return index;}
public void setIndex(int index) {this.index = index;}

}//class closing
```

Process the list as obtained from the data frame and populate the model classes and then convert with Jackson to get the request JSON.

---

The below should do what you are looking for, don't directly run this, the data set is null

```
        //Do not run this, will generate NullPointer, for example only
    Dataset<Row> ds=null;
    List<Row> rows=ds.collectAsList();

    RequestModel request=new RequestModel();

    //Set application id
    ApplicationInfo appInfo=new ApplicationInfo();
    appInfo.setAppId("some id");
    request.setApplicationInfo(appInfo);

    List<RequestData> reqData=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++) {

        //Incrementally generated for each row
        int index=i;

        Row r=rows.get(i);
        int rowLength=r.size();

        for(int j=0;j<rowLength;j++) {

            RequestData dataElement=new RequestData();
            dataElement.setIndex(index);

            switch(j) {

                case 1:{dataElement.setSecureData(r.getString(j));dataElement.setSecureDataType("PID");break;}
                case 3:{dataElement.setSecureDataType(r.getString(j));dataElement.setSecureDataType("FIRSTNAME");break;}
                default:{break;}

            }//switch closing

            reqData.add(dataElement);

        }//for closing

    }//for closing
```

Comment: Edited the Qs as per my requirement. Please take a look.

Comment: Please review my answer section, i have updated the code, but the list is getting overwritten

Comment: Added, the loop to populate the data.

Comment: This will not work because i am not reading all the columns, i only want to read 2 columns out of the 4 cols. And my first and second cols not necessarily will have PID and FIRSTNAME. Also you are not adding reqData to request(RequestModel) anywhere

Comment: I added the line just before the end of second for loop. request.setRequestData(reqData);        } Then printed out the result:  
            for(RequestData reqD:request.getRequestData()){
                System.out.println( reqD.getSecureData()+"  "+reqD.getSecureDataType()+"  "+reqD.getIndex());
            }
Result:
null  null  0
1234567891011  PID  0
null  null  0
null  FIRSTNAME  0
null  null  1
9876543256827  PID  1
null  null  1
null  FIRSTNAME  1

Comment: Please check the loops and debug, I have not tested the above as I do not have the data and Spark instance. Suggestion is to rewrite the above for loops as required and post. I shall have a look.

Comment: Thanks so much Ironluca. I have updated my code in the above answer section. Now trying to deserialize the values and create a dataframe. I am stuck on how to extract the 2 columns- PID and FIRSTNAME which are coming in the response JSON string. Please look at my answer and suggest.