# When serializing my Java map key-value pair to JSON, how can I add JSON keys?

Tags: java, json, serialization, objectmapper

I have a Java map `Map<String, String> map = Collections.singletonMap("dummyKey", "dummyValue")`.
When I use ObjectMapper to serialize it, I get `{"dummyKey":"dummyValue"}`.
Is there any way that I can insert JSON keys in the process of serialization so my JSON string looks like `{"key":"dummyKey", "value":"dummyValue"}`.

I'd like to be able to do this without having to create a separate class, if possible. I'm looking for something like the [allow explicit property renaming](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.8.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ALLOW_EXPLICIT_PROPERTY_RENAMING) feature.

I looked at the other mapper features provided, but can't find anything useful. I don't want to create a different class because I want to retain the ability to be able to use it as a map (look up by key) when I deserialize it later. I'm looking for something that'll only change the way serialization and deserialization happen.

Comment: Create new map.
You can iterate over old one and foreach element add new key value to new map with values from old one.

Comment: You could write a custom serializer for the Map class, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10835504/6465315. I had a similar problem. Like @z48o0 suggested i created an object with my desired structure and then serialized it. I assume there is not much usage to this use case because it is limited to a single Map.Entry...

Comment: Thank you, z48o0 and RainerZufall. But I'm looking for something that I can use to process billions of records. Creating an object to map to and from just for serializing and de-serializing can't be the approach I use.