# Customized serialization in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I have the following class

```
class UserAccount implements Serializable
{
    public String username;
    public String password;

    public UserAccount()
    {
        username = "defaultUsername";
        password = "defaultPassword";
    }

    public UserAccount(String u, String p)
    {
        username = u;
        password = p;
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream o) 
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        //username = (String)o.readObject();
        o.defaultReadObject();
    }

    private void writeobject(ObjectOutputStream o) 
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        //o.defaultWriteObject();

        o.writeObject(username);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return username + ", " + password;
    }
}
```

And I wrote the following snippet to serialize and de-serialize an instance of it.

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("out.dat")));

out.writeObject(new UserAccount("test", "test2"));

out.close();

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("out.dat")));

UserAccount u = (UserAccount)in.readObject();

in.close();

System.out.println(u);
```

I am customizing the serialization using the `writeObject()` hook, such that, I am only persisting the `username`. But when I read back the object, I do the default de-serialization.

I am expecting the output to be `test, null` while the out put is `test, test2`

Basically I am expecting the member `password` to be `null` since I did not persist it. Can anyone help me understand how password is initialized to `test2`.

I also verified that the call to the constructor was not made[I knew it wouldn't be made, but I checked nevertheless] during deserialization.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `transient` keyword to variables to make them **not** serialized. This might be another solution to skaffman's answer.

Reference: [Why does Java have transient fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables/910522#910522)

Comment: That's the right way to go if you just need to skip some of the instance variables of the class.

Answer (score 3):

`writeObject()` doesn't replace the default serialization mechanism, it adds to it (allowing you to add additional data to the stream).

If you want a completely custom mechanism, consider implementing `java.io.Externalizable` instead of `java.io.Serializable`.

From the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html):

> Only the identity of the class of an `Externalizable` instance is written in the serialization stream and it is the responsibility of the class to save and restore the contents of its instances. The `writeExternal` and `readExternal` methods of the `Externalizable` interface are implemented by a class to give the class complete control over the format and contents of the stream for an object and its supertypes. These methods must explicitly coordinate with the supertype to save its state. These methods supersede customized implementations of `writeObject` and `readObject` methods.

Comment: @skaffman...then what is the purpose of `defaultWriteObject()`. I was under the impression that if you omit this line then the default serialization is avoided.

Comment: @skaffman that's only true if the writeObject() method calls defaultWriteObject(), which he isn't doing.