# Unable to serialize instance variable of a non-serializable superclass from the serializable subclass

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, serialization

New to this topic and right now I'm stuck at a brick wall. I have 2 classes, parent class: `Controller.java` and subclass: `GreenhouseControls.java`. I need to serialize a `GreenhouseControls` object but also an instance variable (`eventList`) from its superclass `Controller.java`.

My serialization happens when an inner class of `GreenhouseControls.java` throws a custom `ControllerException`, which is caught in the main method. Before terminating the program, the GreenhouseControls object should be saved (including the field from its superclass).

Why is a `NotSerializableException` thrown by the inner class `WindowMalfunction` of `GreenhouseControls`? Anyone have any ideas, as I am seriously stuck?

What I tried is the following:

1. Implement serializable on `Controller.java`. This is because if the superclass is serializable, then subclass is automatically serializable, however this throws `java.io.NotSerializableException: GreenhouseControls$WindowMalfunction`, (WindowMalfunction is the inner class that throws the initial exception to begin the serialization processs).
2. Implement serializable on `GreenhouseControls.java` and implement custom serialization by overriding `writeObject()` and `readObject()` to save the field from the superclass. This approach yet again throws the same exception as the approach 1.

```java
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        out.writeObject(super.eventList);
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        Object obj = in.readObject();
        List<Event> x = cast(obj);
        super.eventList = x;
}
```

**Controller.java**

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Controller {
    // THIS IS THE VARIABLE I NEED TO SAVE
    protected List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();

    public void addEvent(Event c) {
        eventList.add(c);
    }

    public void run() throws ControllerException {
        while (eventList.size() > 0)
            // Make a copy so you're not modifying the list
            // while you're selecting the elements in it:
            for (Event e : new ArrayList<Event>(eventList))
                if (e.ready()) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    e.action();
                    eventList.remove(e);
                }
    }

    public static void shutDown() { }

}
```

**GreenhouseControls.java** class (note I have removed the inner classes and other code from it and only left related info)

```java
public class GreenhouseControls extends Controller implements Serializable {

    private int errorcode = 0;

    public class WindowMalfunction extends Event {

        public WindowMalfunction(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() throws ControllerException {
            windowok = false;
            throw new ControllerException("Window malfunction");
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Window malfunction";
        }
    }

    public class PowerOut extends Event {

        public PowerOut(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() throws ControllerException {
            poweron = false;
            throw new ControllerException("Power out");
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Power out";
        }
    }

    // Various other inner classes that extend event exist

    public static void serializeObject(GreenhouseControls gc) {
        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        ObjectOutputStream out;
        try {
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream("dump.out");
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(gc);
            System.out.println("WERRROR code: " + gc.getError());
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        out.writeObject(super.eventList);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        Object obj = in.readObject();
        List<Event> x = cast(obj);
        super.eventList = x;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends List<?>> T cast(Object obj) {
        return (T) obj;
    }

    public int getError() {
        return errorcode;
    }

    public Fixable getFixable(int errorcode) {
        switch (errorcode) {
            case 1:
                return new FixWindow();
            case 2:
                return new PowerOn();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GreenhouseControls gc = null;

        try {
            String option = args[0];
            String filename = args[1];

            if (!(option.equals("-f")) && !(option.equals("-d"))) {
                System.out.println("Invalid option");
                printUsage();
            }

            // gc = new GreenhouseControls();

            if (option.equals("-f")) {
                gc = new GreenhouseControls();
                gc.addEvent(gc.new Restart(0, filename));
            }

            gc.run();
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number of parameters");
            printUsage();
        } catch (ControllerException e) {
            String errormsg;
            if (e.getMessage().equals("Window malfunction")) {
                gc.errorcode = 1;
                errormsg = "Window malfunction event occurred Error code: " + gc.errorcode;
            } else {
                gc.errorcode = 2;
                errormsg = "Power out event occurred Error code: " + gc.errorcode;
            }

            logError(errormsg);
            serializeObject(gc);
            gc.displayEventList();
            shutDown();
        }
    }

}
```

**Event.java**

```java
public abstract class Event {
    private long eventTime;
    protected final long delayTime;

    public Event(long delayTime) {
        this.delayTime = delayTime;
        start();
    }

    public void start() { // Allows restarting
        eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + delayTime;
    }

    public boolean ready() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() >= eventTime;
    }

    public abstract void action() throws ControllerException;
```

Comment: @paulk23 added it just now to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event has to be Serializable too.

Change

```
public abstract class Event {
```

to

```
public abstract class Event implements Serializable {
```

Comment: oh wow that was it, could you please explain why Event should be as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476401/what-happens-if-your-serializable-class-contains-a-member-which-is-not-serializa#:~:text=It'll%20throw%20a%20NotSerializableException,that%20field%20a%20transient%20field.&text=Save%20this%20answer.,-Show%20activity%20on

Comment: During serialization all the object classes are given an ID (`static final long serialVersionUID`). If this isn't there the ObjectStream doesn't know how label it when writing or identify it while reading. So the fields `eventTime` and `delayTime` can't be saved either, their owner "Event" doesn't have an id with being tagged Serializable and `serialVersionUID` is automatically generated if not defined by you.