# When to use transient modifier in java?

Tags: java

Can someone explain me real world example of in which situation i can use transient modifier in Java ? I absolutely don't understand its use so far for me ?

```
public transient int a= 55; 
public int a= 55;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

during serialization if you do not want to store any variable then you can declare that using transient keyword