# PrimeFaces datatable fails sorting with active filter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

PrimeFaces Version: 6.0

In my data table I can sort and filter columns but not both at the same time.

Following scenario:

```
Column1               Column2
http://someurl.com       1
http://anotherurl.com    5
```

When I enter a value into the `Column1` filter. Only the filtered rows are visible. Now when I click on sort of `Column1` I get the following result:

```
Column1               Column2
                         0
                         0
```

`Column2` is mapped to a primitive value, that explains the zero value.

As a workaround I have added:

```
<p:ajax event="sort" onstart="PF('mytableWidget').filter();"/>
```

But I can still see the above empty result for some milliseconds, before the `filter()` function is executed.

```
<p:dataTable id="mytable" widgetVar="mytableWidget" value="#{bean.data}" var="item">
<p:column headerText="Column1" sortBy="#{item.column1}" filterBy="#{item.column1}"  filterMatchMode="contains">
    #{item.column1}
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Column2" sortBy="#{item.column2}">
    #{item.column2}
</p:column>
```

`bean.data` is mapped to an `ArrayList<MyDataHolder>`.

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "column1")
public class MyDataHolder {        
    String column1;
    int column2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you must make `MyDataHolder` serializable;

```
public class MyDataHolder implements Serializable
```

My best bet for an elaboration is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985593/importance-of-serializable-interface-while-creating-a-session-scoped-managed-bea) (the same applies to ViewScoped beans). ViewScoped (and broader scoped) beans must be serializable, and therefore all their attributes must be the same.