# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable after PrimeFaces is upgraded to 5.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Does someone get the following exception while redeploying/undeploying the application after upgrading PrimeFaces to 5.1 (community release)?

```
INFO:   Cannot serialize session attribute com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.LogicalViewMap for session 14f27c51ac03df49279d2130b78f
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
        at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:710)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor475.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor188.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor188.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor188.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:438)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.writeObject(Collections.java:2093)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:2195)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.writeSessions(StandardManager.java:761)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.saveSessions(WebModule.java:1730)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2430)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2386)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.stop(WebApplication.java:190)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.stop(EngineRef.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.stop(ModuleInfo.java:324)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.stop(ApplicationInfo.java:380)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.unload(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1056)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.undeploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1096)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.UndeployCommand.execute(UndeployCommand.java:400)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:537)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.handleRedeploy(DeployCommand.java:724)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:537)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Along with the following message.

```
WARNING:   Unable to restore sessions for web module [/Project-war] from previous deployment
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.String to field org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable$MultiSortState.this$0 of type org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable in instance of org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable$MultiSortState
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2063)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1241)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:733)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor231.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1685)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1685)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1685)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1155)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor189.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1685)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1155)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor189.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1155)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor189.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readRemainingObject(StandardSession.java:2078)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1986)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.deserialize(StandardSession.java:1272)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.readSessions(StandardManager.java:555)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadSessions(WebModule.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:537)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

INFO:   Loading application [Project#Project-war.war] at [Project-war]
INFO:   Project was successfully deployed in 36,875 milliseconds.
```

I get this message **quite less frequently** with no logical reason. This never happened prior to PrimeFaces 5.1 final (community release).

---

This should not happen as it is [mentioned](http://blog.primefaces.org/) in the [migration guide](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide),

> There are no breaking changes and 5.1 should be a drop-in replacement
>   from 5.0. Some of the deprecated features are removed.

The migration guide mentions only two points that may cause backward compatibility issues.

> - Support for literal texts in filterBy-sortBy expressions were    deprecated in 5.0 and it is removed in 5.1. These attributes only work with value expression as in the past.
> - Deprecated chart components are removed.

To be a bit clearer. The application at present uses over 100 JSF managed beans. I still do not use CDI beans. Many of them are view scoped, a few of them are session scoped & application scoped and the rest of them (quite a few of them) are request scoped JSF managed beans.

I remember precisely that I nowhere declared `org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable` as a class member in any of the JSF managed beans that I created.

The application is currently running on JSF 2.2.8-02 using GlassFish Server 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7514) in PrimeFaces 5.1 and scheduled to be fixed in a future release.

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=39911

---

**Update:**

This issue has been fixed in respective target versions including **[PrimeFaces 5.2](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/primefaces/primefaces/5.2/)** final (Community Release) as can be seen on the issue tracker.

Comment: +1, good find. You might want to put more detail from that link here, in case the link dies. As it is, this is a link-only answer

Comment: Thank you, @kolossus . I double checked the link and found nothing that can/should be copy/pasted here. [This](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=39911#p126048) replay implies a workaround with a huge code. I would rather choose to wait for a new community release in the future (as this does not harm the entire application. It just fails to restore session(s) from the previous deployment and it is not a much pain - it happens only on redeployment/undeployment of the application) :)

Comment: I reproduced this issue in PrimeFaces 5.1 RC1 about two weeks ago but I initially thought that this might be a problem in my application and did not show it to PrimeFaces guys. Otherwise, it might have already been fixed in PrimeFaces 5.1 final.