# Java object to JSON with only selected fields

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I have java class like:

```
public class Sample{
 int foo=5;
 int bar=6;
}
```

now I want to generate JSON object but without bar field:

```
{"foo":5}
```

What is a best way to accomplish that?
Should I compose JSON string manually, or can I use some library, or generator?

Comment: I'd recommend using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and its `@JsonIgnore`  annotation to ignore non-serializable fields.

Comment: If I remember right, Gson ignores transient fields.

Comment: [There it's a good tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Comment: gson + @Expose lets you choose the exposed fields of your object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Jackson to solve your problem. Follow the below step -

**Step 1** - Make a method which will convert Java object to Json

```
public class JsonUtils {
    public static String javaToJson(Object o) {
            String jsonString = null;
            try {
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                objectMapper.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE,true);  
                jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(o);

            } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
            return jsonString;
        }

}
```

**Step 2**  Model Class

```
package com.javamad.model;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;



public class Sample{
     int foo=5;
     public int getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
    public void setFoo(int foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
    public void setBar(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    int bar=6;
    }
```

**Step 3** Convert your java class to json

```
Sample sample = new Sample()
JsonUtils.javaToJson(sample);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Should I compose JSON string manually

Avoid this, it's all to easy to make invalid json this way. Use of a library ensures proper escaping of characters that would otherwise break the output.

[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) ignores [`transient`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables) fields:

```
public class Sample {
   private int foo = 5;
   private int transient bar = 6;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Or you can choose which to include with `Expose` attribute:

```
public class Sample {
   @Expose private int foo = 5;
   private int bar = 6;
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

Then whichever approach, do this:

```
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

To get your desired `{"foo":5}`

Comment: this works great, but what if I want to select the fields at run time?

Comment: @Mzzzzzz this is too wide to answer in comments. Ask a new question, and explain your usage. Put a link here and I'd be happy to look at it.

Answer (score -1):

you can try Gson, JSON library, to convert object to/from json.

these two methods are helpfull:

toJson() – Convert Java object to JSON format

fromJson() – Convert JSON into Java object

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
// convert java object to JSON format,
// and returned as JSON formatted string
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```