# How to make toJson in Play skip some fields in the model without using external libraries?

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.0

I am trying to create an entity like this

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

  @Id
  public int id;

  public String name;

}
```

However when I do **toJson(person)**, my result contains both the fields `id` and `name`. But I don't want the `id` to be shown.

Is there any annotation or something (like gson's **Expose**, for example) which will make **toJson** *skip some fields* so that the final json output does not contain the `id` field??

**[Short Answer]** - Use   @JsonIgnore (com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore)

Comment: This could be marked as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440902/java-object-to-json-with-only-selected-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

**First,**
In case you need to skip some fields without using external libraries:
You can see original question and answer at:

[Java object to JSON with only selected fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440902/java-object-to-json-with-only-selected-fields)

You can use the @JsonIgnore annotation of Jackson on getter method of that field and you see there in no such key-value pair in resulted JSON.

```
@JsonIgnore
public String name;
```

**Second**, other method is quickly from @ChrisSeline if you using Gson library:

> Any fields you don't want to be serialized in general you should use
>   the "transient" modifier, and this also applies to JSON serializers
>   (at least it does to a few that I have used, including Gson).
>
> If you don't want name to show up in the serialised JSON give it a
>   transient keyword, e.g.,
>
> `private transient String name;`

[Details Here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/)

Comment: yeah gson uses transient. I was asking about play's `toJson` method. Adding transient to `id` field did not help. Ids still come up in my json with '0' as values.

Comment: So, you should read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440902/java-object-to-json-with-only-selected-fields

This will resolve your question.

Comment: Your previous comment is the correct answer but not your post. Would you care to elaborate your comment above and post it so that I can mark it correct?.

Comment: If you see my answer is helpful. Please accept this to other user can see. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Play! uses Gson which doesn´t serialize transient fields.

So I think adding `transient` modifier like this:

```
@Id
public transient int id;
```

should do it.

Comment: how  to do that using just `toJson` method in play, not using gson?

Answer (score 0):

In gson,the most simple way is adding transient as

```
public transient int id;
```

or you can add annotation @Expose and

```
new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

to realize it

Comment: how to do that using just toJson method in play, not using gson.