# How do I serialize/deserialize an object which contains an ArrayList and a HashMap?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have this class:

```
public class Bank  implements Serializable{
    ArrayList<Person> people;
    HashMap<Integer, Set<Account>> bank;

    ...
}
```

How do I serialize/deserialize an object of instance Bank? I found lots of examples on the internet on how to serialize/deserialize a list or a hashMap, but I didn't find an example for serialize/deserialize both or something more complex. How should I do this? Any advice is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Just ensure Person and Account are serializable basically

Comment: both ArrayList and HashMap are serializable, what the issue here ? show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @AmitK Set may or may not be (all of the Collections set implementations are but the interface doesn't make the guarantee). And his custom classes may not be either.

Comment: @Michael , OP is not using set and his custom class are nothing but the the instance of AL and Map and both are serializable.

Comment: oops sorry missed that..

Answer (score 1):

In order for a class to be serializable, either:

1) Each type which it encapsulates must also be serializable

or

2) That field must be [marked as transient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-fields) (which means they are not serialized)

---

Let's look at the types your Bank class is using:

- [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)
- [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)
- Person and Account

The first three are all serializable (as we can see from their JavaDocs) so there's no problem there.

Set is not *by definition* serializable but all of the implementations in `java.util` are so you're *probably* safe. However, if you're relying on the set being serializable you should probably change your definition so it's more explicit:

```
HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Account>> bank;
```

Person and Account are classes which I assume you've written yourself. You haven't provided them but make sure that they also implement serializable. If they aren't also serializable, I believe your ArrayList will throw an exception if you try to serialize it.

---

Additionally, make sure your serializable classes contain a `serialVersionUID`. [What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)