# Deserialize JSON into transient field

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, transient

I have a class with these fields:

```
private transient List<Peer> peers;
private final String name;
private final int points;
private final int size;
```

Using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) I want to deserialize this JSON String request:

```
{
    "name": "game1",
    "points": "11",
    "size": "10",
    "peers": [
        {
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 1234,
            "fullAddress": "localhost:1234"
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem is that the `Peer` object does not get deserialized into the `peers` List unless I don't declare the field as *transient*.

Is there a way, with Gson, to have some field transient only during serialization but not during deserialization?

Comment: That's the point of `transient` keyword in java. It means you can not deserialise the property. You should take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-fields)

Comment: I know. There's nothing that allows me to only deserialize some field and not serialize it?

Comment: @gioaudino Did you try addDeserializationExclusionStrategy() with Gson?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options.

#### excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()

Gson provides `@Expose` that serves the exact purpose. The only caveat here is that you have to annotate *every* field:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
        .create();
```

```java
@Expose(serialize = false) final List<Peer> peers;
@Expose final String name;
@Expose final int points;
@Expose final int size;
```

#### addSerializationExclusionStrategy(...)

Say, you can easily introduce something like this:

```
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface ReadOnly {
}
```

Now, once this one is declared, you can register a strategy to the `Gson` instance:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(final FieldAttributes f) {
                return f.getAnnotation(ReadOnly.class) != null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(final Class<?> clazz) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .create();
```

```java
@ReadOnly final List<Peer> peers;
final String name;
final int points;
final int size;
```

You can easily use `@Expose` for the option #2 by just handling it with something like `f.getAnnotation(Expose.class) != null && !f.getAnnotation(Expose.class).serialize()` in the strategy, but I find `@ReadOnly` somewhat more convenient.

For both options, the following code

```java
public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q43893428.class, "foo.json") ) {
        final Foo foo = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Foo.class);
        for ( final Peer peer : foo.peers ) {
            System.out.println(peer.fullAddress);
        }
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(foo));
    }
}
```

produces the following result:

> localhost:1234
>   {"name":"game1","points":11,"size":10}

Comment: I followed the `@Expose` option, it's pretty quick to use. Thanks

Comment: the addSerializationExclusionStrategy worked like a charm for me! Thanks!