# Android Room: @Ignore vs Transient

Tags: android, serialization, android-room, transient

Are those two interchangable in context of Room database entity, or, if not, what are the differences between them?

Comment: I cannot find reference to transient in Room. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data.html

Comment: transient is the integrated keyword while @ignore is added by Room

Comment: @joao86 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3 https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-transient/index.html

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`@Ignore` is a Room-specific annotation, saying that Room should ignore that field or method.

`transient` is a Java construct, indicating that [this field should not be serialized in standard Java serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/910522/115145). [Room *happens* to treat this similarly to `@Ignore` by default](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62600692). Mostly, that is there for cases where you are inheriting from some class that happens to use `transient` and you do not control that class (e.g., it is from a library).

For your own code, if you are not using Java serialization, I recommend sticking with `@Ignore` for the fields. `transient` is not an available keyword for a method, so to tell Room to ignore certain constructors, you have no choice but to use `@Ignore`.

Answer (score 18):

*Adding to CommonsWare's answer*

---

`transient` is not good option for ignoring fields for Room as CommonsWare answered. It will create blocker when same modal is being used to parse data from server and store into database.

Let's assume you have a modal class `MyModal.java` as below

```
public static class MyModal {

    @SerializedName(“intField”)
    public int intField;
    @SerializedName(“strField”)
    public String strField;
    @SerializedName(“booleanField”)
    public boolean booleanField;
}
```

If you want to NOT SAVE booleanField into database, and if you modified that field as

1. `transient` : It will ignore this field while saving into database, BUT it will also ignore this field while parsing data which comes from server.
2. `@Ignore` : It will only ignore this field while inserting data into database, but this field will participate into json parsing.

Comment: And how do I:
Ignore this field while json parsing, but include it in database?

Comment: Found answer to my own comment: `@ColumnInfo(name = "show_id")`
`public transient String showId;`

Comment: Most of the time we need the inverse of this.