# How to make Room ignore a field in the data model?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to run a select query on Room. I have the following Dao:

```
@Dao
abstract class TopicDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Topic WHERE Id = :topicId")
    abstract fun getTopicModel(topicId: String): LiveData<TopicUiModel>
}
```

the following Entity:

```
@Entity
data class Topic(
    @PrimaryKey
    val Id: String,
    val Name: String,
)
```

and the following data model:

```
data class TopicUiModel(
    val Id: String,
    val Name: String,
    val Selected: Boolean,
)
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
"There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: Selected)"
```

The error makes sense but how do I make room to ignore this field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Room: @Ignore vs Transient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718206/android-room-ignore-vs-transient)

Comment: Using @ Ignore or @ Transient gives the followign error: "Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type)."

Comment: did you try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485631/room-persistence-errorentities-and-pojos-must-have-a-usable-public-constructor

Comment: Instead of this, `LiveData<TopicUiModel>` change return type to `LiveData<Topic>`

Comment: @VarshaKulkarni In this case it seems trivial, however, the actual model is more complicated than I showed here. Your solution corresponds to creating a separate and extremely similar data class for every single model I have and use MutableLiveData to cast between them. Just for this one flag, I didn't want to go down that path.