# Ignore columns that do not exist in the database

Tags: java, azure-mobile-services

I am using a mobile service of azure.

Example:

I have the ToDoItem class that consists of 4 fields

Id, Text, Complete, State.

In the database in the cloud is only: Id, Text, Complete but the field State does not and at the time of trying to insert a data in the cloud one throws me the error 400: because the column Status is not in the scheme of the table
My question is:

How can I ignore the State field when inserting a record?

Comment: question is: why did you add you add it to the query?

Comment: Is that the application needs to have a backup of the information that is in the cloud, then at the time of saving some data and does not have internet it saves it in a SQLITE database and that's when the field is used state

Comment: You specify column names you are interested in when inserting like - insert into cloud_table (id, text, complete) select id, text, complete from sqlite_table

Comment: Yes, the problem is not when saving a data in SQLite, but it is when I try to save it in the Cloud using the Mobile Service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaEE you can annotate those fields with `@Transient` annotation. 
Using `@Transient` you can have a field which shouldn't persist it.

Check this question:
[Why does Java have transient fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-fields)

Comment: Could you please approve my answer?