# why Kotlin Object class to json object comes null?

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

I am trying to convert kotlin object class using Gson() to JSON string but it gives back null where as object fields are actually holding the values. if it's a singleton object why can't I directly use to convert it in JSON string?

```
 val gson =  Gson()
 val dummy= Dummy
 val objDummy = gson.toJson(dummy)
```

object class:

```
object Dummy: Serializable{

   var test2: String? = "test2"

   var blank: String? = null

   var test1: String? = "test1"

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties in `object` will be translated to static filds that are implicitly [transient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-fields)

You can use `GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT)` to allow Gson to serialize such filds.

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT).create()
val dummy = Dummy
val objDummy = gson.toJson(dummy)
```

Also, it is pointless to use `Serializable` for `object`

Comment: do you think, storing data in singleton object class and then use that directly to send it as JSON is a good way?

Answer (score 0):

oh i am even facing this problem. all you have to do is to install json to kotlin plugin from intellij idea plugin and i am sure it works fine and even works in nested json

Comment: I guess you miss understood the question. My question is on converting from kotlin object to json.