# Why doesn't the shared static variable update in the threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, static-variables, critical-section

I am trying *Peterson's Solution* for the *Critical Section Problem*, and I noticed that my static variable doesn't update unless I add a `System.out.print("");` statement.

Why is this so?

Thanks.

The code for `Peterson.java` is below:

```java
public class Peterson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Process p1 = new Process(0);
        Process p2 = new Process(1);
        p1.start();
        p2.start();
        p1.join();
        p2.join();
    }
}

class Process extends Thread {
    static int turn;
    static boolean[] wait = new boolean[2];

    int ind;
    public Process(int ind) {
        this.ind = ind;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int ind2 = 1-ind;
        wait[ind] = true;
        turn = ind2;
        
        // USING THIS WORKS
        // while(wait[ind2] && turn == ind2) {System.out.print("");}
        // USING THIS DOESN'T WORK
        while(wait[ind2] && turn == ind2) {;}

        // Critical Section
        System.out.printf("%d Started%n", ind);
        for (long t = System.currentTimeMillis(); System.currentTimeMillis() - t < 100;);
        System.out.printf("%d Ended%n", ind);

        wait[ind] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `static volatile int turn;`

Comment: Wow, That was all that it took :)

Comment: Is there any chance you know what is `transient`?

Comment: transient: [JLS 8.3.1.3. transient Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3): "*Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part of the persistent state of an object.*" and for example used in [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html): "*The default serialization mechanism for an object writes the class of the object, the class signature, and the values of all non-transient and non-static fields.*"

Comment: and maybe this question: [Why does Java have transient fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-fields)